# gradle docker plugin bmuschko Splitting a build.gradle into two files gives error

Tags: docker, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to using gradle scripts.  I have a build.gradle file that I want to split into two files.  I get the following two files once I split the larger build.gradle file.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.12.RELEASE'
        gradleDockerVersion = '3.2.7'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
project.ext.imageName = 'myImage'
project.ext.tagName ='myTag'
project.ext.jarName = (jar.baseName + '-' + jar.version).toLowerCase()

apply from: 'dockerapp.gradle'
```

**dockerapp.gradle**

```
def gradleDockerVersion = '3.7.2'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerRemoveImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile

def imageName = project.ext.imageName
def tagName = project.ext.tagName
def jarName = project.ext.jarName

task createAppDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    // Don't create dockerfile if file already exists
    onlyIf { !project.file('Dockerfile').exists() }
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Generate docker file for the application'
    dependsOn bootRepackage
    destFile = project.file('Dockerfile')
    String dockerProjFolder = project.projectDir.name
    from 'openjdk:8-jre-slim'
    runCommand("mkdir -p /app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder} && mkdir -p /app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/conf")
    addFile("./build/libs/${jarName}.jar", "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/")
    environmentVariable('CATALINA_BASE', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    environmentVariable('CATALINA_HOME', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    workingDir("/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    if (System.properties.containsKey('debug')) {
        entryPoint('java', '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n', '-jar', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/${jarName}.jar")
    } else {
        entryPoint('java', '-jar', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/${jarName}.jar")
    }
}

task removeAppImage(type: DockerRemoveImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Remove the docker image using force'
    force = true
    targetImageId { imageName }
    onError { exception ->
        if (exception.message.contains('No such image')) {
            println 'Docker image not found for the current project.'
        }
    }
}

task createAppImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Executes bootRepackage, generates a docker file and builds image from it'
    dependsOn(createAppDockerfile, removeAppImage)
    dockerFile = createAppDockerfile.destFile
    inputDir = dockerFile.parentFile
    if (tagName)
        tag = "${tagName}"
    else if (imageName)
        tag = "${imageName}"
    else
        tag = "${jarName}"
}
```

If I try to run the command `./gradlew createAppImage` I get an error as follows:

[image: Gradle error]

The other two tasks within dockerapp.gradle file seem to work without issues.  If I place all my code within the build.gradle file, it works properly without giving any errors.  What is the best way to split the files and execute createAppImage without running into errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with help from CDancy (maintainer of the plugin) as follows:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.12.RELEASE'
        gradleDockerVersion = '3.2.7'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}    

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'    

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}    

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}    

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'    

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
project.ext.imageName = 'myimage'
project.ext.tagName ='mytag'
project.ext.jarName = (jar.baseName + '-' + jar.version).toLowerCase()    

apply from: 'docker.gradle'
```

docker.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.7'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
// use fully qualified class name
apply plugin: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.DockerRemoteApiPlugin    

// import task classes
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*    

def imageName = project.ext.imageName
def tagName = project.ext.tagName
def jarName = project.ext.jarName    

task createAppDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    // Don't create dockerfile if file already exists
    onlyIf { !project.file('Dockerfile').exists() }
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Generate docker file for the application'
    dependsOn bootRepackage
    destFile = project.file('Dockerfile')
    String dockerProjFolder = project.projectDir.name
    from 'openjdk:8-jre-slim'
    runCommand("mkdir -p /app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder} && mkdir -p /app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/conf")
    addFile("./build/libs/${jarName}.jar", "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/")
    environmentVariable('CATALINA_BASE', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    environmentVariable('CATALINA_HOME', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    workingDir("/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}")
    if (System.properties.containsKey('debug')) {
        entryPoint('java', '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n', '-jar', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/${jarName}.jar")
    } else {
        entryPoint('java', '-jar', "/app/springboot/${dockerProjFolder}/${jarName}.jar")
    }
}    

task removeAppImage(type: DockerRemoveImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Remove the docker image using force'
    force = true
    targetImageId { imageName }
    onError { exception ->
        if (exception.message.contains('No such image')) {
            println 'Docker image not found for the current project.'
        } else {
            print exception
        }
    }
}    

task createAppImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description 'Executes bootRepackage, generates a docker file and builds image from it'
    dependsOn(createAppDockerfile, removeAppImage)
    dockerFile = createAppDockerfile.destFile
    inputDir = dockerFile.parentFile
    if (tagName)
        tag = "${tagName}"
    else if (imageName)
        tag = "${imageName}"
    else
        tag = "${jarName}"
}
```

The change was basically in my docker.gradle file , I had to add the repositories section that pointed to `jcenter()` and to use fully qualified plugin class name.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why would you ever want to use Docker Plugins in your Gradle? After playing some time with the most maintained [Mushko's Gradle Docker Plugin](https://bmuschko.com/blog/dockerized-spring-boot-app/) I don't undersand why should one build **plugin boilerplate over docker boilerplate** both in varying syntax?

Containerizing in Gradle is comfortable for programmers and **DevOps would say they don't work Docker like this** and you should go their way if you need support. I found a **solution below that is short, pure Docker-style and functionally full**.

Find normal Dockerfile and docker.sh shell script in the project structure:

[image]

In your `build.gradle` file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }

    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'application'
    }

    // Entrypoint:

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.Test'
        }
    }

    mainClassName = 'com.example.Test'

    // Run in DOCKER-container:

    task runInDockerContainer {
        doLast {
            exec {
                workingDir '.' // Relative to project's root folder.
                commandLine 'sh', './build/resources/main/docker.sh'
            }
    //        exec {
    //            workingDir "."
    //            commandLine 'sh', './build/resources/main/other.sh'
    //        }
        }
    }
```

Do anything you want in a clean shell script following normal Docker docs:

```
    # Everything is run relative to project's root folder:

    # Put everything together into build/docker folder for DOCKER-build:
    if [ -d "build/docker" ]; then rm -rf build/docker; fi;
    mkdir build/docker;
    cp build/libs/test.jar build/docker/test.jar;
    cp build/resources/main/Dockerfile build/docker/Dockerfile;

    # Build image from files in build/docker:
    cd build/docker || exit;
    docker build . -t test;

    # Run container based on image:
    echo $PWD
    docker run test;
```

Comment: In your case, it's fine to have a static Dockerfile. In other cases, you may want to leverage Gradle's "dependsOn" command to have dynamically built Dockerfiles whose contents may change based on other dependencies in your project. I have it set up this way to build 6 dockers in a single master project and my dockers are only built when their dependencies change. It's very efficient and makes it unnecessary to mix Gradle tasks with shell scripts.